# Предусмотреть для пользователя выбор вариантов ответов на вопрос: «Ошибка устранена?» - ответы «Да», «Нет», «Невозможно устранить»

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net, asp.net-core

Добрый день, как я могу это реализовать, лучше всего  на c#.

Моя модель.Не уверен нужен ли тут bool(столбец)

```
public class Fila
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsItDone { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "DateOfCreated")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Date_Of_Eliminate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Предусмотреть для пользователя выбор
вариантов ответов на вопрос: «Ошибка устранена?» - ответы «Да», «Нет»,
«Невозможно устранить». При этом предусмотреть следующее условие: если
ответ – «Да» (ошибка устранена), то пользователю предлагается
ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО указать дату из календаря; если ответ «Нет» или
«Невозможно устранить», то ввод дополнительных данных не требуется.

Comment: если у вас выбор из трех вариантов - bool не подойдет (даже bool? = null это скорее "неизвестно") используйте Enum. или строку.

Answer (score 0):

Вам должен подойти Enum:

```
public enum Answer
{
    Yes,
    No,
    Impossible
}
```